# LXC/LXD containers in Ubuntu 18.04 network issues

Tags: 18.04, lxc, network-bridge, lxd

I've got an Ubuntu 18.04 system setup as a VPS host to start migrating containers from an EOL 14.04 VPS host. I've got a bridge (br0) configured to allow the containers to have IPs on the same vlan as the host. But I am seeing packet loss on the bridge when trying to ping/access the containers. which seems extremely odd.

here is the netplan config on the host (internal IP subnets changes):

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
           dhcp4: no
           dhcp6: no
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [eth0]
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses:
                - 10.10.10.5/24
            gateway4: 10.10.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 1.1.1.1
                - 8.8.8.8
            parameters:
                stp: false
                forward-delay: 0
```

and the client:

```
network:                                                                                                                                                                               
  version: 2                                                                                                                                                                           
  ethernets:                                                                                                                                                                           
    eth0:                                                                                                                                                                              
      dhcp4: no                                                                                                                                                                        
      addresses: [10.10.10.6/24]                                                                                                                                                     
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1                                                                                                                                                           
      nameservers:                                                                                                                                                                     
              addresses:                                                                                                                                                               
                      - 1.1.1.1                                                                                                                                                        
                      - 8.8.8.8
```

If i am unable to access the hosts via the network but open a shell session w/ LXC and ping  out all the sudden the network works.

I've been banging my head on this since Thursday.

(one of the containers seems to be working but it already has a live SIP trunk that is qualifies at 60 seconds as well)

Comment: Did you enabled the paquet forwarding on the host ?

Comment: I had not explicitly, but it shouldn't work intermittently I'd think it is what is confusing me more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was much simpler than I had figured, I had build out a base container that I was cloning to get to the point that each container I spun up could be configured mostly identically. when cloning containers the MAC on eth0 was duplicated, leading to network issues.